# Improvements to Ask Ubuntu or wiki, help

Tags: discussion

I am constantly frustrated by the amount of out of date information  or misleading information given in a question:answer(s) format. I call this "Fubar disinformation" which can lead you down many rabbit holes trying to fix a problem. Not only that, but lead to irrecoverable damage to your system.

So I'm asking for a format or wiki that culls out disinformation ,  finds the best direct and easiest solution(s) and vets them (they need to be corroborated and replicated). Then they are presented in a wikipedia style for ease of use and searchability.

Does this already exist or is this forum the best that is offered now?

Signed "lost in the subterranean rabbit matrix"

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Also see: [Why are all the questions/answers on this site so old and out of date?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20178/why-are-all-the-questions-answers-on-this-site-so-old-and-out-of-date/)

Comment: I have also explored this topic once: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19458/1157519

Comment: Terdon, as always, has presented a great answer for you. Could I suggest as well that if you are interested in culling disinformation on Ask Ubuntu specifically: assemble yourself some more rep points and join the chat site that covers many editing issues on Ask Ubuntu: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat

Answer (score 9):

I don't quite understand. You are describing the Stack Exchange format. It was designed, [from the very beginning](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/), as a system that incorporates features of wikis, forums, Digg/Reddit and blogs:

[image: SE venn diagram showing it is a mix of wiki, blog, reddit and forum]

If you find wrong information, well these sites are designed to act as wikis and allow collaborative editing. So edit! Fix the errors!

As for finding "the best direct and easiest solution(s)", well that's what upvotes, downvotes, and accepts are for.

So, if you find wrong answers: downvote. If you can fix them: edit them. If you find good answers: upvote. If the right answer is missing because everything is out of date: post a new answer with the up to date solution. If someone gives you the right solution to your question: accept.

In other words, you already have all the tools to do what you describe, just use them.

Comment: But this does not solve the striving that we want _all_ the information to _be optimal all at once_!

Comment: @Levente no, we need to work for it. That's precisely the point of these sites: we are here to build a library of information and we all need to do our part curating it.